# Remove a UITableViewCells button when clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I Have a button within a uitableview cell -

[image]

I have set it up to trigger a fmethod when clicked - (the function displays messages and resets the message count).

my code for this method is as follows -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Define Custom Cells

    static NSString *CellCountI =@"CellCount";

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    feedData *f = [self.HpFeedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    //Comparison Strings
    NSString *count = @"Count";

    //If statement Cell Filters
    //If Count Cell
    if ([f.FeedGroup isEqualToString:count]) {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellCountI forIndexPath:indexPath];

        HP_Header_TableViewCell *hpTC = (HP_Header_TableViewCell *)cell;

        hpTC.buttonPressedSelector = @selector(buttonImpMsg);

        hpTC.buttonPressedTarget = self;

        [hpTC.msgsBtn setTitle: f.FeedTitle forState: UIControlStateNormal];

        return hpTC;
    }
}
```

The buttonImpMsg method is as follows -

```
- (void)buttonImpMsg
 {
    NSLog(@"Back Button Pressed!");

   [self removeBtn];
 }
```

I would like to hide the button when clicked - but I'm not sure how to reference it from the buttonImpMsg method?

Comment: i think , better will be to make it hidden, if you want to again.

Comment: cheers @pawan - how would i reference it to make it hidden though in this context?

Comment: your sender is , reference of button. - (void)buttonImpMsg:(UIButton*)sender{  sender.hidden = YES;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the delegate pattern, IMHO, it's the most proper way.

> i think , better will be to make it hidden, if you want to again. –  @pawan

I would also hide the button rather than remove it.

Try this implementation to hide the button, you can also do the same thing to hide this one after.

> TableViewCell.h:

```
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@implementation TableViewCell

//.... Connect your action or set selector to this method:

- (IBAction)hideButton:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;

    // hide the button by using the setter
    button.hidden = YES;

    //.... Check if the delegate method has been implemented
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(hideButton)]) {
        [_delegate hideButton];
    }
}

@end
```

> TableViewCell.h

```
//... Declare the delegate:
@protocol CellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)hideButton;

@end

@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell

//... Add a delegate property:
@property (strong, nonatomic) id <CellDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

> ViewController.m:

```
//... set self a the delegate of your cell
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//...
    cell.delete = self;

    return cell;
}
```

> ViewController.m:

```
//... 
@interface ViewController () <CellDelegate>
//...

//... Implement the delegate method if you need to do stuff on the controller side
- (void)hideButton
{
    //do stuff here if needed
}
```

Comment: no worries ;), you could also passe send the button tag to your delegate method if you need to retrieve the index of the current cell
`- (void)hideButton:(NSInteger)row` `[_delegate hideButton:button.tag]`

Answer (score 3):

Pass the sender to the selector:-

```
- (void)buttonImpMsg:(id)sender { 
     [sender removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: cheers @borncrazy - all cool but i get an error stating property 'tag' not found on object of type '_strong ID'.

Comment: You could pass along the indexPath in a similar way to identify the button.

Comment: why "int tag  =  sender.tag;"  , [sender removeFromSuperview]; is enough to remove the sender from superview.